# Injected HttpClient Missing Base Address

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject a simple `HttpClient` with a preconfigured `BaseAddress` into a class.

```cs
private static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext hbc, IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationExchangeClient, AuthenticationExchangeClient>(); //Nb. This wasn't shown originally, added for context after solving question. This line is the problem.
    services.AddHttpClient<AuthenticationExchangeClient>(c => c.BaseAddress = new("http://api.mendeley.com"));
}
```

```cs
public class AuthenticationExchangeClient : IAuthenticationExchangeClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;     
        
    public AuthenticationExchangeClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this is in-line with the dotnet 5 docs.

When I run it, the `HttpClient` *is injected* into the `AuthenticationExchangeClient` but `client.BassAddress` on this injected client is `null`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: TBH works just fine for me. Can you post full repro?

Comment: @GuruStron - Solved it, but thanks anyway. I've also edited the original question to show the line that was breaking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that I was registering the `AuthorisationExchangeClient` as a transient service as well like this:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationExchangeClient, AuthenticationExchangeClient>();
```

When I get rid of that line, and change my `HttpClient` line to this, it works:

```cs
 services.AddHttpClient<IAuthenticationExchangeClient, AuthenticationExchangeClient>(c =>                                                                   c.BaseAddress = new("http://api.mendeley.com"));
```

It seems as though `AddHttpClient` pulls double-duty, registering both the `HttpClient` and the service.